# Sub Not Defined Error: Calling a Macro in Another Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to call a sub from another sub and am getting a Sub Not Defined error.

I'm trying to run a macro that hides a row in Sheet4 when a specific cell in Sheet1 changes.

Here is my code for Sheet1:

```
Public Sub HiddenValidations()
    If [O18]=true then call test
End Sub
```

Here is my code for Sheet4:

```
Public Sub test()
    Rows("7").entirerow.hidden=true
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help!

-Kim

Comment: Note: the subroutine test() runs on it's own, but when called, a 'sub not defined' error comes up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to qualify your macro name:

```
Public Sub HiddenValidations()
    If [O18]=true Then Sheet4.test
End Sub
```

(And there is no need for the `Call` to invoke a macro - as far as I know, it exists only for backward-compatibility reasons.)

Comment: @khelm - please mark the answers that fixed your issues as accepted (click on the check mark next to the answer), for both your questions